# Помогите разобраться, почему всегда выводится ноль?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Взял за основу алгоритм решения задачи о рюкзаке из книги Седжвика, но программа работает неправильно. Почему-то всегда возвращается ноль. В его книге код прокомментирован очень плохо: о назначениях переменных говорится где-то далеко в самом начале, причем там говорится даже не о переменных, а о вводе таких-то чисел, обозначенных M. Код получается очень неприятным, и его трудно оформить в красивую процедуру. Помогите хотя бы разобраться, почему всегда выводится ноль.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>

typedef struct{
    int size;
    int val;
} Item;

const int n = 10;   // Число предметов
const int m = 50;   // Емкость рюкзака
const int size = 50;

Item items[n];
int max_known[size];
Item item_known[size];

int knap(int cap){
    int space;
    int max;
    int maxi;
    int t;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        std::cout << max_known[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if(max_known[cap] != -1) return max_known[cap];
    for(int i = 0, max = 0; i < n; i++)
        if((space = cap - items[i].size) >= 0)
            if((t = knap(space) + items[i].val) > max){
                max = t;
                maxi = i;
            }
    max_known[cap] = max;
    item_known[cap] = items[maxi];
    return max;
}


int main(){
    std::memset(max_known, -1, size * sizeof(int));

    // Создаем рандомные вещи
    std::srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        Item it;
        it.size = 1 + std::rand() % 15;
        it.val = 1 + std::rand() % 701;
        items[i] = it;
    }

    std::cout << knap(m) << std::endl;

    int pause;
    std::cin >> pause;
}
```

Comment: Возьмите отладчик и посмотрите как именно программа работает.

Answer (score 1):

Вы вызываетесь от элемента массива `max_known[50]`, которого, вообще говоря, нет и там явно не -1.

Чтобы избавиться от массивов и `memset` используйте `std::vector<int>`. Ну и еще круто не инициализировать что-то в условиях :)

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что бросается в глаза: вы в теле функции создаете переменную неинициализированную `max`, a в инструкции инициализации цикла создаете другую переменную `max`, которую инициализируете нулем.

В итоге в теле цикла изменяется вторая переменная, та, что была создана в начале цикла (и в конце цикла будет удалена), а возвращается первая, неинициализированная.

P. S. Я не проверял сам алгоритм.

P. P. S. Компилируйте с `-Wall`, это всегда полезно.

P. P. P. S. А еще, скажите на милость, зачем вам глобальные переменные?

Comment: Насчет создания переменной в заголовке цикла: я теперь сделал так, чтобы переменные создавались в начале функции, а в цикле только инициализировались. Так пойдет? Но программа все равно работает неправильно. И что делать с глобальными переменными, например, с массивами? Некоторые программы пишутся с красивой программной логикой, а все эти алгоритмы надо либо с помощью нескольких классов реализовывать, либо вот так писать в стиле 70-х годов. https://ideone.com/1h1H4A

Comment: Вот так, вроде, работает. Можете посоветовать, как улучшить архитектуру программы? https://ideone.com/mQbUJn

Comment: Очень просто. Нужно разобраться в алгоритме и написать самому =) А если по делу, избавьтесь от глобальных переменных и констант — это всегда хорошо.

Comment: Я разобрался и знаю, как заполняется двумерная таблица для этого алгоритма. От констант избавиться можно, а как избавиться от массивов, если их размер вообще-то должен меняться в зависимости от входных данных?

Comment: Передавать их в функцию. Или создавать непосредственно в функции (`new` / `delete`).